# Hibernate annotation mapping for nullable entities

Tags: hibernate, annotations, mapping

I have 2 tables:

```
Table A
   Id (primary key)
   Name
   request_Id 



Table B
   request_Id (primary key)
   request_param
```

the relation between these 2 tables is by the request_id, although, there is no foreign key constraint, which means, a record can exist in table A even if there is no record for that request_id in table B. I would also state that this is a unidirectional relationship from A --> B

The following are the annotated mappings for the 2 tables:

```
@Entity...
class A
{
   @Id
   private int id;
   @Column
   private String Name;
   @Column(name="request_id")
   private String requestId
   @ManyToOne(optional = true)
   @JoinColumn(name="request_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private B b;
}

@Entity...
class B
{
   @Id
   @Column(name="request_id")
   private String requestId;
   @Column(name="param")
   private String param;
}
```

consider this table data:

```
  table A
    id = 1
    name = "temp"
    request_id = "A"
```

there are no records in B

when I load entity A for a record in A that does not have a corresponding record in B, i get an exception, "org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists"

I print the sql, and I see 2 queries, one for table A with an outer join for table B and then another query for Table B.

I am not sure why it does it. When I execute the first query in DB, it works fine. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong or provide some pointers to resolve the issue?

Comment: If you're using a column as a foreign key and that column is not null, then you're telling Hibernate that there should be a corresponding entity in the other table. Given the data, that's not the case. Why isn't `request_id` set to `null` since there is no corresponding row in the foreign table? Put another way: why does it make sense to have a non-null value in table A's `request_Id` when there are no rows in table B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason to have a non null value in table A when there is no record in table B is because table B is an afterthought. the design caters to a requirement to perform some tasks if there are records in table B, Otherwise the process terminates.

I was avoiding using `@NotFound`, but I don't think I have any other choice, or is there, keeping the same table design?